# Передача параметра через ссылку в js onclick!

Tags: php, javascript

Нужно вызвать функцию `js` при нажатии на ссылку.

Ссылка формируется динамически, сразу после формирования ссылки с изображением, изображение формируется хорошо - с тем же параметром, а вот ссылка по нажатию на которую нужно вызвать функции не работает, ошибка `ReferenceError: minIMG_1167 is not defined.`

**Код:**

```
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    $pos1 = stripos(strval($file), "min");
    if ($pos1 !== false) {
        //echo '<img src="'.$path.iconv('cp1251', 'UTF-8',     $file).'">';
        $filem = str_replace("min", "", $file);
        $i++;
        if ($i==1) {
            echo "<div style='float:left;'><a class='group1  cboxElement' href='".$path.iconv('cp1251', 'UTF-8',  $filem)."' style='padding:2px;'><img src='".$path.iconv('cp1251', 'UTF-8',$file)."'></a></br><a href='#' onclick='delfoto(".$file."); return false;'>Удалить</a></div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div style='text-align:left;'><a class='group1  cboxElement' href='".$path.iconv('cp1251', 'UTF-8',  $filem)."' style='padding:2px;'><img src='".$path.iconv('cp1251', 'UTF-8',$file)."'></a></br><span onclick='delfoto(".$filem.")'>Удалить</span></div>";
            $i=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно поставить кавычки для параметра функции `delfoto`

```
echo " ... delfoto(\"".$file."\") ... "
```